# JAVA: JPA: Doesn't persist Strings that contain %

Tags: java, jboss, jpa-2.0

I'm inserting a record using JPA 2.0. The record is persisted. However, one attribute is inserted as an empty String when the value contains the %, & characters. Debugged to the point where the value is being set and everything seems fine. Also, i'm doing a URLEncode.encode on the value before setting it.

- Value before encoding:`<p>asd%</p>`
- Value after encoding: `%3Cp%3Easd%25%3C%2Fp%3E%0A`

Code:

```
a.setContent(URLEncoder.encode(this.article, "UTF-8"));

public void setContent(String val){
    this.content = val; //on debug i see that the value after encoding is set.
}
```

My gut says that there is config issue with utf characters.  checkout my persistence.xml

```
    <persistence-unit name="dude.Abortion" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <description>JBOSS Hibernate Provider</description>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:jdbc/dbsomedb</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>com.dude.had.an.abortion</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value=""/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to log the SQL including parameters? Can you show this in a short but complete program?